# Proof that N lines on a plane can be painted in 2 colors ,so that no 2 neighbor sectors , formed by this lines, are in the same color.

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, induction

N lines are drawn in a plane. We need proof that there is always a way to  paint the sectors in 2  colors, so any two neighbor sectors are in different colors .

I know that this should be made by induction and that the base case is for 1 line,but i don't know how to proceed .Any tips?

Comment: Your title says that the lines are to be painted, but the body of your question says that the sectors (which you haven't defined but I don't think they are lines) are to be painted. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

Induction. Let there are two colors: $1$ and $-1$. We start with no line and all the points are colored by 1. Let there are $n+1$ lines. Ignore any line then the coloring exists and each point (excluding those lying on line) is colored by $1$ or $-1$. The additional line devides plane in 2 parts and "multipliers" the collors of all points by 1 on the one side on the line and by -1 those on the other.

PS. It is important that the lines have no colors otherwise the coloring may not exist - take three lines having one point in common.